# Adding a value to a List which is based on a Model

Tags: c#, .net, list, generic-list

**Backgournd**

I am currently trying to add a value to a list of a model however it seems to be different than how I would do it in JavaScript.

**Model**

```
public class ContentBase
{

    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string library { get; set; }
    public string ContentSummary { get; set; }        
    public string[] images { get; set; }
}
```

**Function To Add Value**

```
 List<ContentBase> returnList = new List<ContentBase>();
 foreach (HtmlNode img in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
  {
    HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];
    returnList.Add(images = att.Value);  << this is wrong, just trying to give an idea of my intentions
  }
```

**Question**

I am trying to add the result from  `HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];` into `string[] images` of my list.  That way once I complete this iteration I will be able to have all the values which I get from my for each loop in the `string[] images` part of my list

**Update**

This is the preceding function that populates the other items in my list

```
string content = "";
if (includeContent == true)
{
    content = rslt[ContentBase.fastContent] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fastContent].ToString() : "";
}

returnList.Add(new ContentBase()
{
    UniqueId = rslt[ContentBase.fasstUniqueId] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fasstUniqueId].ToString() : "",
    LastModifiedTime = rslt[ContentBase.fasstLastModifiedTime] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fasstLastModifiedTime].ToString().Substring(0, 8) : "",
    Name = rslt[ContentBase.fastName] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fastName].ToString() : "",
    Description = rslt[ContentBase.fastDescription] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fastDescription].ToString() : "",
    KeyWords = rslt[ContentBase.fastKeyWords] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fastKeyWords].ToString() : "",
    ContentSummary = rslt[ContentBase.fasstContentSummary] != null ? rslt[ContentBase.fasstContentSummary].ToString() : "",
    Content = content,

});
```

Comment: Trying to add att.Value to the Images property inside of return list

Comment: Would the list contain only a single `ContentBase` element which you set its `images` property?

Comment: Was away, yes it will contain the elements which are received from my for each loop.  The element count will be dynamic not static

Comment: The for loop only can provide `images` which belong to a single `ContentBase`. Where do the other `ContentBase` objects come from?

Comment: @RezaAghaei  it come from a sharepoint request I will provide the code as soon as I get back to my desk.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  posted the additional code requested.

Comment: Eventhough I may not have an answer, but I think it may be a good Idea for you to push all items at once if not you will get list items that will only contain the image Url

Comment: @Staffer901 So just put `images` property in your `new ContentBase` this way: `images = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img").Select(x=>x.Attributes["src"].Value).ToArray();` Like I did in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `returnList` is a `List<ContentBase>`, so you should add a new `ContentBase` to the list.

The `ContentBase` object contains a `string[] images` property which you can create in the loop or using linq and pass it to the new `ContentBase` created. You also should provide value of other properties of created `ContentBase`. For example:

```
var returnList = new List<ContentBase>();
returnList.Add(new ContentBase()
{
    // Initialize properties the same way you are setting them
    // Including the images property this way:
    images = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
                         .Select(x=>x.Attributes["src"].Value).ToArray()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `returnList` is a List of `ContentBase` so its items should be the objects of the corresponding class. So the code to add items to this will be like the following:

```
foreach (HtmlNode img in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
  {
    HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];
    returnList.Add(new ContentBase(){library="some value",images = new string[]{att.value}}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `ContentBase` object first and then add it:

```
 List<ContentBase> returnList = new List<ContentBase>();
 foreach (HtmlNode img in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
  {
    HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];
    ContentBase base = new ContentBase();
    base.image = att.value;
    returnList.Add(base);
  }
```

Comment: I think `base.image = att.value;`  will be wrong since `att.Value`  will be a string and `base.image` will be a string array

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq without even using the `foreach` loop, like this:

```
List<ContentBase> returnList = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
     .Select(img => new ContentBase {images = new[] {img.Attributes["src"].Value}}).ToList();
```